# (Answered) How to insert DataExtension rows (via REST API) by other primary key (not email address)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, dataextensions, rest

I have a DataExtension containing a primary key that is not an email address.  I'd like to use a RESTful API that allows me to insert several rows into the DataExtension in a single request (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm).  So I've created a DataExtension that is a modified version of the example.

Thanks to @JayantDas for help with this!

JSON payload:

`[
    {
        "keys":{
            "mypk": "12345"
                },
        "values":{
                "Email": "john_smith@somewhere.com",
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys": {
            "mypk": "12347"
                },
        "values":{
                "Email": "jane_smith@somewhere.com",
                "LastLogin": "2018-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": false,
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "FollowerCount": 3,
                "LastName": "Smythe"
                }
    }
]`

Comment: Are you missing a comma (,) after "Email" in the values?

Comment: Would also help if we saw an example of the endpoint you are using

Comment: @TravisNaughton Thanks for the comment.  The endpoint was in the link I posted.

Comment: Updated my question with the answer.

Comment: Sure, I added that as an answer to be able to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON payload had a missing comma(,) after Email attribute. Fixing that resolved the issue.

Comment: great catch. :+1: